# Rewrite program from Console to WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying rewrite game "guess word" from C# console to C# windows form, and I have 1 problem I don't know how to stop loop ant 2 time read word from textbox

```
while (true)
{
  guess.Text  = Console.ReadLine(); // how to stop loop here and read new word from textbox?

  if (guess.Text=="#")
    break;

  if (guess.Text.CompareTo(secretWord) == 0)
  {
    bGuessedCorrectly = true;
    break;
```

Comment: i suggest you're doing it wrong. don;t use a loop, it's wasting cycles - bind an event to the text changed event of the textbox and in that event do your processing of whatever is in the box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Windows Forms application, the main loop is actually already maintained by the form and operation system. The form will fire *events* when user input is detected, such as a mouse click or a keystroke. You, as a developer of the GUI (Graphical User Interface), *subscribe to an event* that you're interested in, like a "submit" button click, and then run the appropriate logic.

Usually, When developing a UI, you would use a *designer* which is a tool in your IDE (e.g. Visual Studio) which allows you to design the layout of your controls (buttons, checkboxes etc.). In Visual studio, double-clicking a control, will subscribe to the default event of that control (in the case of a button, it will subscribe to a click event and will even generate an *event handler* (a method), to write the logic for that event:

```
 private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string guessedWord = textBoxGuessedWord.Text;
        if (guessedWord == _secretWord)
        {
            _guessedCorrectly = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _guessedCorrectly = false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not how GUI applications work. They are event-based. A thread is running in the background waiting for user input, hence using another loop is redundant. When you input something in a textbox (and maybe push a button) an event is raised which you must handle with a method.

I suggest you read some tutorials about Windows Forms / WPF.